# Free jqGrid 4.9.0 - sopt menu overlayed when grid is in a modal

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

When I'm bringing up the grid from within a bootstrap modal, the sopt menu is being opened at the back, so basically user can't see it.

Is there any trick I can change the z-index so that it will go into the front?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provides the demo which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Thanks Oleg, It's gonna take me some time to do that.  Maybe, I can show you how I "fixed" it, so you can understand the issue:  If I add a style z-index:999999 to the <ul id="sopt_menu" class="ui-search-menu" role="menu" tabindex="0" style="font-size:' + fs + ";left:" + left + "px;top:" + top + 'px; z-index:999999;">';  (within the jquery.jqgrid.src.js) it solve the issue.  The issue is because the Modal Z-index is higher than the default z-index of the spot_menu element.

Comment: It's the same what I made in my local copy of `9999` which is still higher as `z-index: 1050` used for modal dialogs and even higher as `1070` used in bootstrap for tooltip. I will post the changes to GitHub. Thank you for reporting of the problem!